# Topology Choice - Countable Space

Tags: general-topology, discrete-mathematics, continuity

Consider a countable (possibly finite) state space $S=\{1,2,...\}$ (discrete).

Moreover, consider a function $f$ defined on $S$ as follows : $f:S\to[a;b]$ for any finite $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

How can you choose the topology in such space such that $f$ is continuous? Is the discrete topology the most natural topology for such "countable discrete" space?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Every function with out of a space with the discrete topology is continuous

Comment: I understand. However, is it the most natural topology for such countable discrete space? Thank you.

Comment: Your topology on S needs to be in a way such that S is not connected or else you can't have a continuous map to an interval, because the interval is uncountable.(assuming $a < b$)

Comment: I am very new to topology but I understood that any function from a discrete topologic space to any other space is continuous. Therefore the uncountability of the interval should not be important?

Answer (score 1):

If a topological $(X,\tau_d)$ is equipped with the discrete topology every function $f: X\to T$ where $T$ is a generic topological space is continuous. So you are absolutely right if you give to S the discrete topology you are sure that $f$ is continuous. The most "sure" I would say is the discrete topology. Anyway in general depending on the spaces, you can try to give to $X$ some coarser topologies, to have your function $f$ continuous.